# Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing tests (with Jest and React Testing Library) for a form React component. I have a method that runs on form submit:

```js
const onSubmit = (data) => {
  // ...
  setIsPopupActive(true);
  // ...
};
```

and `useEffect` that runs after `isPopupActive` change, so also on submit:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (isPopupActive) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsPopupActive(false);
    }, 3000);
  }
}, [isPopupActive]);
```

In the test, I want to check, whether the popup disappears after 3 seconds. So here's my test:

```js
it('Closes popup after 3 seconds', async () => {
    const nameInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Imię');
    const emailInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Email');
    const messageInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Wiadomość');
    const submitButton = screen.getByText('Wyślij');

    jest.useFakeTimers();

    fireEvent.change(nameInput, { target: { value: 'Test name' } });
    fireEvent.change(emailInput, { target: { value: 'test@test.com' } });
    fireEvent.change(messageInput, { target: { value: 'Test message' } });
    fireEvent.click(submitButton);

    const popup = await waitFor(() =>
      screen.getByText(/Wiadomość została wysłana/)
    );

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(popup).not.toBeInTheDocument(); // this passes

      expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 3000);
    });
  });
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function setTimeout]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 25):

**Jest 27** has breaking changes for fakeTimers. It seems Jest contributors doesn't update documentation on time. [This](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11713#issuecomment-892694162) comment on Github issues confirms it. Moreover, [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/11731) related PR.

Well, you can solve your problem by two ways.

1. Configure Jest to use legacy fake timers. In **jest.config.js** you can add line (but it not works for me):

```js
module.exports = {
 // many of lines omited
 timers: 'legacy'
};
```

2. Configure legacy fake timers for individually test suite, or even test:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers('legacy');
describe('My awesome logic', () => {
// blah blah blah
});
```

It's preferably to use new syntax based on [@sinonjs/fake-timers](https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers). But I can't find working example for **Jest**, so I'll update this answer as soon as possible.

Comment: option 2 listed here worked for me. I wish developers didn't release new versions without the corresponding docs. What's the rush if the docs aren't ready yet??

Comment: It looks like these docs might be relevant https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks

Answer (score 3):

The below approach worked

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');
});

afterEach(() => {
  global.setTimeout.mockRestore();
});

it('Test if SetTimeout is been called', {
  global.setTimeout.mockImplementation((callback) => callback());
  expect(global.setTimeout).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 7500);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `setTimeout` is not a mock or spy, rather, it's a real function. To make it a spy, use `const timeoutSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'setTimeout')`. And use `timeoutSpy` in the assertion.

You could also test not the fact of calling the `setTimeout` function, but assert that `setIsPopupActive` was called once, and with `false`. For this you might need to do `jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()` or `jest.runAllTimers()`

Comment: Unfortunately, when I replaced `setTimeout` with `timeoutSpy`, it says that the function received hasn't been called at all. `jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()` and `jest.runAllTimers` didn't help either. Are there any other options?

Comment: Did you try passing 'modern' argument as a string into `jest.useFakeTimers()`?

Comment: I have the same problem and the expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); is explicitly mentioned in https://jestjs.io/fr/docs/timer-mocks ...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue after I upgraded jest and fixed it.
You can make spy for setTimeout or other timer related functions and then test whether it is called or not. For exmaple :

```
let setTimeoutSpy = jest.spyOn(window,'setTimeout');
// call you function which you want to test
jest.runAllTimers();
expect(setTimeoutSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```